# Help parsing a nested JSON object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, json, nsdictionary

**I have the following JSON**:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    }, 
    "response": {
        "deals": [
            {
                "id": 32373, 
                "date_added": "2011-01-13 12:12:50", 
                "end_date": "2011-01-14 10:00:00", 
                "active": 1, 
                "discount": {
                    "raw": 71, 
                    "formatted": "71%"
                }, 
                "price": {
                    "raw": "85.00", 
                    "formatted": "$85"
                }, 
                "value": {
                    "raw": "300.00", 
                    "formatted": "$300"
                }, 
                "purchased": 82, 
                "left": null, 
                "title": "$85 For $300 Babyface Facial At Park Avenue MedSpa", 
                "yipit_title": "71% off Babyface Facial", 
                "url": "http://yipit.com/aff/click/?deal=AvwTADtE&key=F374EFbM", 
                "yipit_url": "http://yipit.com/new-york/livingsocial/85-for-300-babyface-facial-at-park-avenue-medspa/", 
                "images": {
                    "image_big": "http://d22nv2k05ynu7x.cloudfront.net/deal_images/deal/85-for-300-babyface-facial-at-park-avenue-medspa-1294920769_display_image.jpg", 
                    "image_small": "http://d22nv2k05ynu7x.cloudfront.net/deal_images/deal/85-for-300-babyface-facial-at-park-avenue-medspa-1294920769_small_image.jpg"
                }, 
                "division": {
                    "slug": "new-york", 
                    "name": "New York", 
                    "active": 1, 
                    "time_zone_diff": -4, 
                    "lat": "40.7142690000000000", 
                    "lon": "-74.0059730000000000", 
                    "url": "http://yipit.com/new-york/"
                }, 
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "name": "Facial", 
                        "slug": "facial", 
                        "url": "http://yipit.com/new-york/deals/facial/"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "name": "Spa", 
                        "slug": "spa", 
                        "url": "http://yipit.com/new-york/deals/spa/"
                    }
                ], 
                "business": {
                    "name": "Park Avenue MedSpa", 
                    "url": "", 
                    "locations": [
                        {
                            "address": "565 Park Ave", 
                           "locality": "New York",
                            "phone": "212-593-8821", 
                            "lat": null, 
                            "lon": null
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                "source": {
                    "name": "LivingSocial", 
                    "slug": "livingsocial", 
                    "paid": 0, 
                    "url": "http://yipit.com/new-york/livingsocial"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Here is how I am parsing it:**

```
    NSArray *deals = [[results objectForKey:@"response"] valueForKey:@"deals"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[results objectForKey:@"response"] valueForKey:@"deals"]);

    for(NSDictionary* deal in deals)
    {
        NSLog(@"Title: %@", [deal valueForKey:@"title"]);
        NSLog(@"URL: %@", [deal valueForKey:@"url"]);
        NSLog(@"Value: %@", [[deal valueForKey:@"value"] valueForKey:@"formatted"]);
        NSLog(@"Picture URL: %@", [[deal valueForKey:@"images"] valueForKey:@"image_small"]);
        NSLog(@"Business: %@", [[deal valueForKey:@"business"] valueForKey:@"name"]);
        NSLog(@"Address: %@", [[[deal valueForKey:@"business"] valueForKey:@"locations"] valueForKey:@"address"]);
        NSLog(@"City: %@", [[[deal valueForKey:@"business"] valueForKey:@"locations"] valueForKey:@"locality"]);
        NSLog(@"Phone: %@", [[[deal valueForKey:@"business"] valueForKey:@"locations"] valueForKey:@"phone"]);

        [items addObject:deal];
    }
```

My logging looks good except for **Address**, **City** and **Phone**. Here is the log:

```
Title: $10 for $20 Worth of Food and Drinks at Blondies in Tempe
URL: http://yipit.com/aff/click/?deal=cHBPNZ3w&key=93HU7t2d
Value: $20
Picture URL: http://d22nv2k05ynu7x.cloudfront.net/deal_images/deal/50-off-at-blondies-sports-bar-1298454745_small_image.jpg
Business: Blondies Sports Bar
Address: (
    "501 S Mill Ave"
)
City: (
    Tempe
)
Phone: (
    "702-737-0444"
)
```

Comment: From the JSON you provided, `locations` is an array, so the values that are returned from `valueForKey:` are contained in NSArray instances (hence the parentheses).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the JSON you provided, `locations` is an array (that's what the square brackets mean), so the values that are returned from `valueForKey:` are contained in NSArray instances (hence the parentheses).

You could use `objectAtIndex:` before the last call to `valueForKey:` to obtain just the value you're looking for.

By the way, you can also use `valueForKeyPath:` to simplify accessing nested values, for example

```
[deal valueForKeyPath:@"business.name"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm interested in valueForKeyPath, I did not know that. I tried your following snippet, but it returns null. Could you edit your answer to show the full code?

Comment: The call to `valueToKeyPath:` in the example above can be a substituted for expressions like this (from the code you posted) `[[deal valueForKey:@"business"] valueForKey:@"name"]`, and mean essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`[[deal valueForKey:@"business"] valueForKey:@"locations"]` returns an array. Calling `-valueForKey:` on an `NSArray` executes `valueForKey:` for every object in the array and returns an array of the results (see the NSArray documentation for this). So that's what you get, an array of the corresponding values.

Comment: Still a bit confused, can you show me how to pull that value out from the NSArray that is returned?

Comment: Use `objectAtIndex:` to get at an item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

**You could try changing your code to something like this:**

```
NSDictionary *primaryLocation =  [[[deal valueForKey:@"business"] valueForKey:@"locations"] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Address: %@", [primaryLocation valueForKey:@"address"]);
NSLog(@"City: %@", [primaryLocation valueForKey:@"locality"]);
NSLog(@"Phone: %@", [primaryLocation valueForKey:@"phone"]);
```